# message notification after save button (python, html)

Tags: python, html, django

```
<form name="import_csv" id = "import_csv" action = "{% url 'mission:import-csv' mission.id %}" method = "post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
{% if message %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

The {{message}} contains a message of " You have uploaded successfully". I want to show the message after save the file. Can someone please help me run this program correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try to get in the views.py if the request is post then render the same html with the message parameter.

Something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   return render(request, 'app/your.html', 
                    context_instance = RequestContext(request,
                        {  
                            'message':'Your message'
                        }
                    )
                )
```

And may be you are extending a layout and it`s under the block.`{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

first try this:

{% block content %}

```
<form name="import_csv" id = "import_csv" action = "{% url 'mission:import-csv' mission.id %}" method = "post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
{% if message %}
     <div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

if it won`t work then please post the url route, the associated view function,and the html